# Command works when run from alias but not when typed?

Tags: bash, alias

I use to type this command a lot :

```
sshfs 10.xxx.xx.4:/Users/username/code mountpoint
```

So one day i put it as an alias on my .bash_profile as

```
alias sshfs='sshfs 10.xxx.xx.4:/Users/username/code mountpoint'
```

and started to use the alias all the time

i have noticed that now after a few months if i copy/type the command directly into the terminal i get "Fuse: invalid argument" error but if i continue to use the alias it works fine.

What's going on here?

Comment: It's *always* using the alias. Thus, when you type in `sshfs 10.xxx.xx.4:/Users/username/code mountpoint`, it expands the alias and winds up trying to run `sshfs 10.xxx.xx.4:/Users/username/code mountpoint 10.xxx.xx.4:/Users/username/code mountpoint`, and the extra arguments cause `sshfs` to complain. You need to name the alias something different from the command to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use a different name for your alias. For example (one of mine):

```
alias ipex='curl -s http://ipecho.net/plain'
```

Or, in your case:

```
alias s4='sshfs 10.xxx.xx.4:/Users/username/code mountpoint'
alias s8='sshfs 10.xxx.xx.8:/Users/username/code mountpoint'
```

and so on.

You may use more complex aliases, or even personal functions used inside aliases, for example when you need to pass a parameter inside the command, not at the end (as to provide a changing IP address to your alias), but it is probably a bit too much depending on your question.

Anyway, this is one of mine, again:

```
# Delete an existing alias, but only if it exists in order to avoid an error:
dont_alias() {
    alias $1 >/dev/null 2>&1 && unalias $1
    return $?
} # dont_alias
```

Then I use dont_alias as an alias, for example:

```
dont_alias s4 # Will unalias the existing s4
dont_alias s7 # Will do nothing
```

The only difference with aliases is that functions do not appear in the list of (existing) aliases.

I have a few more complex samples (that I use daily), if some people are interested. Please feel free to ask for — I do my best to come here every few days :^)